# Vertical text on charting using html5 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, vertical-text

I am developing chart PoC with HTML5 canvas.

the each text AA, BB and so on are all canvas. I am generating them by h`var canvas = $("<canvas></canvas>").appendTo(elementDiv);` and using loop to display the text.

I am using `ctx.fillText(txt, x - txt.length * 2, 18);` to display the text.

Here, my question is how to make them as vertical text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn the text into vertical text, you simply use the `rotate` method to apply a rotate transform to your canvas:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations#Rotating

You might also need the `translate` transform to correctly position your text after rotation, play around with transforms until you figure out how they work (you can skip this step if you know your matrices)